# MS SQL Server Mirroring / Clustering / Replication

Tags: sql-server, database, database-mirroring, database-cluster

I have a client that requires a web page for registration. This web page will show up as soon as a customer joins the wifi of the venue. 
All registration information will be pushed to a MS SQL Server.

The point here is that this client has two locations, in two different countries. Each country will have its own DB and they should have exactly the same data. Also, if one of the MSSQL Server is down the other should take the requests.

Mirroring does not seems to be the answer since only one server is active at a time. I understand clustering neither since both servers will have to share the same storage. 
Should I just create these two DBs as separate and implement a replication service (both ways) so any data coming in one DB will be sent to the other one ?

Thanks and regards,

Comment: In your case [Merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152746(v=sql.110).aspx) replication might be the best choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Practical feasible solution in your case is to have MERGE replication.